# How can I prevent an audio player to pause when a second player starts playing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soundcloud

I'm building an app using AngularJS, and I'm using the soundcloud API to stream sounds through two different players.

My problem is that I want to have both the players to play sound simultaneously, which is not happening at the moment.

```js
angular
.module('mtcApp')
.controller('PlayerCtrl', PlayerCtrl);

PlayerCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function PlayerCtrl($scope){

  $scope.startPlayerA = function(track){
    const id = track.id;
    console.log(id);
    SC
      .stream(`/tracks/${id}`)
      .then(function(player){
        $('#playA').on('click', function(){
          player.play();
          
        });
        $('#pauseA').on('click', function(){
          player.pause();
          console.log(player);
        });
      });
  };

  $scope.startPlayerB = function(track){
    const id = track.id;
    console.log(id);
    SC
      .stream(`/tracks/${id}`)
      .then(function(player){
        $('#playB').on('click', function(){
          player.play();
        });
        $('#pauseB').on('click', function(){
          player.pause();
        });
      });
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="">
    <div class="">
      <div ng-controller="PlayerCtrl as vm">


        <div class="fl w-50 mv3 bg-grey">
          <h3>Deck A</h3>
          <button id="playA"> **PLAY** </button>
          <button id="pauseA">**STOP**</button>
        </div>
        <div class="fl w-50 mv3 bg-grey">
          <h3>Deck B</h3>
          <button id="playB"> **PLAY** </button>
          <button id="pauseB">**STOP**</button>
        </div>
        
        <sc-search></sc-search>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is happening now is that if $scope.startPlayerA.player is playing and $(#playB) is clicked, $scope.startPlayerB.player starts playing but $scope.startPlayerA.player stops, anyone has an idea of how i can prevent this from happening?

thanks

Comment: I was trying to find some evidence in the soundcloud JS SDK source, but the relevant code is minified and obfuscated and I didn't feel like going through that, but my educated guess is that the players returned in the promises are linked to some singleton instance of an `Audio()` that disallows you from having multiple simultaneously playing streams.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I've actually found out that there's a useSinglePlayer option of the player, which is set on true by default, changing that to false fixed my problem!